# MYSQL find rows where foreign key are not in related table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have reservations that can be made in advance. On the day of the reservation, the devices reserved can be checked out.

I have two tables, reservations and checkouts. Reservations have many checkouts.

How would I construct a query that would return all reservations for a particular date that do NOT have associated checkout records?

To put it another way, all rows from reservations where reservation_id column does not contain the reservation's ID?

So far, my best guess is

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservations.id NOT IN (SELECT reservation_id 
FROM checkouts)
```

But that returns empty. Here's a rough idea what the tables look like

```
|reservations|  |checkouts         |
|id = 1      |  |reservation_id = 1|
|id = 2      |  |reservation_id = 2|
|id = 3      |
```

My result should be reservation 3.

P.S. If php is required, that's fine.

Comment: Your current query does seem to give the desired result. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69916/1)

Comment: Query is compeltely fine.

Comment: Most likely explanation for no rows being returned is that there's at least one row in `checkouts` that has a NULL value in the `reservation_id` column. If that's the case, the result from the `NOT IN` predicate will be NULL, which means no rows will be returned. See my answer.

Comment: There are NULL reservation_id because some items are checked out without a reservation. I'm going to verify, but I think this is the answer.

Comment: @crowhill: seems entirely reasonable that items could be "checked out" without a prior reservation. And it would be reasonable that a NULL value in the reservation_id column would model the "no relationship to a reservation." (You were just being bitten by the `NOT IN (NULL)` problem. The "fix" is to make sure there's never a NULL in that list. And there are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result, demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely explanation for the query returning no rows is that there are rows in `checkouts` that have a NULL value for reservation_id. Consider:

```
4 NOT IN (2,3,5,NULL,11)
```

In interpreting this, the NULL value is seen as meaning "unknown what the value is". Is 4 in that list? The answer (coming back from SQL) is basically "unknown" whether 4 matches the "unknown" value in the list.

If that's what's causing the behavior, you can "fix" your current query by including `WHERE reservation IS NOT NULL` in the subquery.

```
SELECT r.* 
  FROM reservations r
 WHERE r.id NOT IN ( SELECT c.reservation_id 
                       FROM checkouts c
                      WHERE c.reservation_id IS NOT NULL
                   )
```

This may not be the most efficient approach to returning the specified result. An anti-join is a common pattern for returning this type of result.  In your case, that would be an outer join, to return all rows from `reservations`, along with matching rows from `checkouts`, and then a predicate in the WHERE clause to filter out all the rows that had a match, leaving us with rows from `reservations` that didn't have a match.

For example:

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM reservations r
  LEFT
  JOIN checkouts c
    ON c.reservation_id = r.reservation_id
 WHERE c.reservation_id IS NULL
```

It's also possible to get an equivalent result with a `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM reservations r
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM checkouts c
                     WHERE c.reservation_id = r.reservation_id
                   )
```

Comment: It's the top example. Works great. Thank you! That one had been bothering me all morning.

Comment: @crowhill: whenever you have a `NOT IN (list)`, you want to either *make sure* there's never a NULL in that list, or, if you are going to allow a NULL in the list, you are *expecting zero rows* will satisfy the predicate.